# Cabling into concrete

Tags: wiring, cabling

So I've been doing the installation of a lot of cctv systems recently and the most time consuming part of it is always the cabling. Currently I am using coax cable clips to hold the cable. The issue is that using the cable clips if I hit a hard section of pebble dash or concrete and mortar I end up with about a 5% success rate of getting the clips in which is not in any way shape or form efficient.

So what I was wondering is what i sthe most efficient way to cable into concrete (external walls) that is a durable and not too offensive looking.

I've had a look at using a ramset but I can't work out how that would functionally work with the cabling in a safe manner (i.e. not firing 2mm away from a finger).

If a staple gun style thing existed which could fit over a coax cable that would probably be optimal.

Comment: I have used a Ramset with metal clips. don't use the plastic ones the Ramset nails blow right through the plastic ones. Put the clip on the coax, load the round and nail push in directly over the hole this will hold the clip in place and your hand doesn't need to be close. If you use a single cartridge gun make sure to pick up the brass. The last time I got pinched I think it was 50$ per round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a powder actuated tool (like Ramset) and use [short drive pins with a washer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ramset-1-in-Drive-Pins-with-Washers-100-Pack-00797/100559049)?

[image: ramset pin]

Insert these in a line where you want the cable. Before firing, wrap a wire/cable tie of some sort under the washer.

```
 Images and links are illustrative, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramset on a cable clip could work because the "nail" fits up into the barrel of the tool, so you could place the clip on the cable and hold it in place with the tool, not your fingers. But those are tools you need to throughly understand the correct and safe operation of, so if you try that, please be sure that you have read, and understand, and are following the recommended procedures.